# Passing complex model to controller using targeted AJAX and ASP

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pass a model to the controller in ASP.NET. There are two ways to do this: with Ajax.BeginForm and with JQuery. I have attempted both of these techniques. I would prefer to get the Ajax.BeginForm to work but I have had more luck with JQuery.

My page gives a list of responsibilities stored within the KnowledgeTransfer model to be edited and saved by the KnowledgeTransfer controller. The user edits and clicks the "AddKnowledgeTransfer" button to send the model to the controller (not shown) which returns a partial view. The partial view is one question within a larger survey form to be completed and submitted.

Some requirements: My form is a partial view within a larger form, nested, so I must target the correct Ajax and controller method, not submit the entire page. (I read this may be impossible? I have been able to get close with jQuery. If impossible, can I submit the form with only one level of hierarchy?) Another requirement I have is I must automatically pull the entire KnowledgeTransfer model. There are literally hundreds of properties in the model so I need to pull them all, not list them out like some examples show.

Here is the Ajax.BeginForm technique:

```
    @model KnowledgeTransfer

    <partial name="_MainResponsibilities" />


    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateMainResponsibilities2",
            "KnowledgeTransfer",
            null,
        new AjaxOptions()
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "mainResponsibilitiesList"
        },
        new { id = "MainResponsibilitiesForm" }))
        {

    <div class="form-group" id="mainResponsibilitiesList">
        <table id="ResponsibilitiesTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-sm-5">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MainResponsibilities[0].Responsibility)
                    </th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.MainResponsibilities.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr style="border-bottom:thin">
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.MainResponsibilities[i].Responsibility, new { id="responsibility_" + i, @style = "width:90%; margin:auto; border-style:none;" })
                        </td>      
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <button class="btn col-sm-2" value="Create" type="button" name="MainReponsibilities" onclick="document.getElementById('MainResponsibilitiesForm').submit();" id="AddResponsibility" title="Add Responsibility"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add Responsibility</button>

    }
```

The problem with this code is that the button cannot find the MainResponsibilitiesForm ID and therefor cannot submit it.

Now for the second jQuery technique:

```
@model KnowledgeTransfer

<partial name="_MainResponsibilities" />

<div class="form-group" id="mainResponsibilitiesList">
    <table id="ResponsibilitiesTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-sm-5">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MainResponsibilities[0].Responsibility)
                </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.MainResponsibilities.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr >
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.MainResponsibilities[i].Responsibility)
                    </td>                    
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<button class="btn col-sm-2" value="Create" type="button" id="AddResponsibility2" title="Add Responsibility">Add Responsibility</button>

<script>
    $("#AddResponsibility2").click(function () {
            var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
            var url = "@Url.Action("UpdateMainResponsibilities2", "KnowledgeTransfer")";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: JSON.stringify(model),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function () {
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        })
</script>
```

With JQuery I am able to pull the model using   `var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));` But this calls the server and updates the model from the database, not from the model that has changed on the client side. So maybe I can use Json.Encode() to pull the model, and then edit the JSON object to update the values? This seems unnecessary.Working with the JSON may also be difficult because I have to iterate over the structure to identify the each element. I would probably need to dynamically label the elements in the HTML to select them too.

I should have used Angular, haha. But this app doesn't use it anywhere else, so here I am.

If you have any suggestions on how I can improve this post, please let me know. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why would you prefer `Ajax.BeginFor()`? - its effectively obsolete, has been dropped from asp-net-core mvc, and is no longer recommend by the mvc team. And nested forms are invalid html and not supported.

Comment: It difficult to understand what your issue is since you have not shown any code relating to nested forms. But why in the world do you have `location.reload();` in the success callback - the whole point of ajax is to stay in the same page, so using that make no sense at all (and is just degrading performance)

Comment: I am learning on MVC. I did not know Ajax.BeginFor was obsolete.

Comment: Does the jQuery submit count? Technically it is not wrapped in a form so it is valid?

Comment: Obsolete in terms of MS no longer recommending it. What do you mean by _jQuery submit count_ (what 'count' are you referring to? And why are you posting back the original unedited mode? Its not clear at all what you are wanting to do here.

Comment: What I mean is by using JQuery Ajax post method, does this violate the form-within-a-form constraint?  What do you mean by "posting back the orgininal unedited mode"?

Comment: Without the location.reload() the section does not re-draw.

Comment: What do you mean by _form-within-a-form?. (nested forms are invalid html and not supported). And `var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));` is the original model that your sent to the view (razor code is evaluated on the server before its sent to the client, so you are just sending back exactly what you sent to the client). And again, the whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page! Using `location.reload()` makes no sense - you update just the part of the DOM that you want to

Comment: And you do realize that `Ajax.BeginForm()` is just a wrapper around the `$.ajax()` method?

Comment: When I update the database with the UpdateMainResponsibilities2 post, I need to pull the data from the database again after the controller has done its work, such as adding a new MainResponsibility object. That is why I use location.reload, to partially refresh this section. Is this post considered a "form"? I have a form tag around the entire page but not in this section.

Comment: If you just adding the html for a new `MainResponsibility` in the view, then your method should return just a partial view of that, and in the success callback, you append that partial to the DOM (but its still unclear what you are actually wanting to do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to pass the model to the controller uses the ID parameter.

```
<tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.MainResponsibilities.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr >
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.MainResponsibilities[i].Responsibility, new{id="responsibility-" + 1})
                    </td>                    
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

I pull the model from the database, re-write the model values on the client...

```
<script>
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

function MainResponsibilitiesLoop(callback) {
    for (i = 0; i < model.MainResponsibilities.length; i++) {
        var thisResponsibility = document.getElementById("responsibility_" + i);
        thisResponsibility = thisResponsibility.value;


model.MainResponsibilities[i].Responsibility = thisResponsibility;
</script>
```

Then I save the updated model to the server with an AJAX call.

```
<script>
function SaveOverview(callback) {
    var url = "@Url.Action("UpdateMainResponsibilities", "ResponsibilitiesController")";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function () {
            callback();
            }
        }
    )
}
</script>
```